# Angular 5 - HttpClient Service - Component not getting data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-services, angular5

I am using Angular 5 and trying to get some data from JsonPlaceholder.

First I created the service, then added:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

This is the service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private ROOT_URL = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getPosts() {
    this.http.get(`${this.ROOT_URL}/posts`).subscribe(data => {
      return data;
    });
  }

}
```

And finally, on my app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  data;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {

    this.data = dataService.getPosts();
    console.log(this.data;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

On the console it's just returning 'Undefined'

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: you  need to subscribe()

Comment: @MicheleDibenedetto He did :)

Comment: Your code works fine for me. If I `console.log(data.json())`, I get an array of 100 objects in my console. You just need to use the `data` and not simply return it.

Comment: oh, sorry I did not notice :)

Comment: @MicheleDibenedetto The code works with console.log but not with 'return' for some reason

Comment: you did subscribe in the "wrong" place.. or better say you are logging in the wrong place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code snippet.
You are getting `undefined` because you assigning the data before the `http` request could resolve a value. Remove the subscription from service and move it to component.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private ROOT_URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getPosts() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.ROOT_URL}/posts`);
  }

}
```

AppComponent.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from './data.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ] 
})
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(public data:DataService){

    this.data.getPosts().subscribe(data=>{
      console.log(data);
    })
  }

}
```

See the [**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1dxlpd) here

Comment: Please tak a look at my answer also. Doing it like in answer above, not in resolver will result in slight delay of presenting data after entering the page.

Answer (score 2):

Don't subscribe on the service, return the observable and subscribe to it on the component. Because it is asynchronous your data variable on the component will be undefined because you assigned before the http request could resolve a value.

On the service:

```
getPosts() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.ROOT_URL}/posts`);
}
```

On the coponent:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getPosts().subscribe(posts => this.posts = posts);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
//This is the service code:

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private ROOT_URL = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getPosts() {
  //if you want to use the observable which returns from .get()
  //.. you need to do "return"
   return this.http.get(`${this.ROOT_URL}/posts`);
  }

}
 
//app.component.ts:

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  data;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {

    this.data = dataService.getPosts();
    //so if you want to use the value of your http call outside.. 
    //..of the service here is a good place where to do subscribe()
     this.data.subscribe(data => {
       console.log(this.data;
    });
  
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You expect a return value and returns nothing. Your return statement is placed inside a nested-lambda function, thus using "return" in the place you used it causes the inner function to return a value, and not the outer one as you needed.

I suggest you to read about asynchronous programming, and particularly about Observable (which works on the same concept of Promise) in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I basically agree to @Eduardo Vargas answer, but it might be also a good idea to do it in resolver, which will call api, and put data into route snapshot. Thanks to this it won't wait on empty page for loading the data on subscribe in constructor. More info here:

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html